# Query to Access Sharded Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am querying a vendors database that has data that is sharded between multiple tables. The tables are named `Events_1`, `Events_2`, `Events_3`, `Events_4` etc.

It appears that a new table is automatically created when the table hits 10,000 records. I am looking to write a query that would be able union the results from all the tables (without having to manually add the tables as they are created) as well as a query to only look at the 2 newest tables.

Any suggestions on the best way to go about this?

The database is Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: 1. Sharding like this after 10k records seems misguided at best. You would have to create dynamic sql base don sys objects.

Comment: Such is the way the vendor set it up.   I might be close to a solution using a cursor.   Ill post the results.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do this with dynamic SQL such that you query sysobjects for table name Events_* and build a SELECT UNION from the results.
2. Better, though perhaps more complicated, would be a DDL trigger that would dynamically update you UNION VIEW to append the new table whenever a table Events_* was created.